# Xcode 8 doesn't print assertion message (for example when NSInternalInconsistencyException crash occurs)

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, lldb, nsassert

Something is wrong with my project. It doesn't print assertion messages when debugging application and the app crashes. Normally it should display something like this:

```
2017-02-05 20:13:54.687 MyPlayground[29372:221950] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.6.21/UITableView.m:1610
2017-02-05 20:13:54.690 MyPlayground[29372:221950] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (10) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (10), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

But all I get is first message. I only know that assertion failed and I get no explanation why. This makes debugging a lot more difficult than it should be because of not knowing what is the cause of the crash.

```
2017-02-05 20:07:00.958 myProject[28876:215448] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.6.21/UITableView.m:1315
```

I looked around and someone suggested that this might be because optimizations are turned on, but that's not the case. Both my project and target have optimization for debug set to None and I'm sure I'm running my project with debug configuration. I tried everything I could and nothing helped so far, I'm running out of ideas what this might be.

I'm using Xcode 8, project is mixed Swift 3.0 + Objective-C. I used to have cocoapods, but I switched to Carthage (I hoped that this might help, but that wasn't it).

Comment: I have similar issue. Any one help?